# Changing the color of Forex API numbers when the value changes

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, api

I am trying to figure out how to change the color of the numbers. The thing is i am building an app with React.js that uses forex API to display the values of each currency rate, so i am trying to figure out how to change it to green if the number goes up, stay the same if its the same value and red if the number goes down. The colors should show for only one second. The Javascript of it and how to change the color is the problem. I will appreciate a little help, thank you.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Infocard2 from "./infocard2";
import Forexcard from "./forexcard";

export default class Forexdata extends Component {
state = {
time: "",
NGN: "",
EUR: "",
CNH: "",
JPY: "",
GBP: "",
AUD: "",
CAD: "",
CHF: "",
SEK: "",
NZD: ""
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.api_call();
    setInterval(api_call(), 30000);
  }

  api_call = () => {
    axios.get(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.freeforexapi.com/api/live?pairs=USDNGN,USDEUR,USDCNH,USDJPY,USDGBP,USDAUD,USDCAD,USDCHF,USDSEK,USDNZD`
  ).then(res => {
          this.setState({
          time: res.headers.date,
          NGN: res.data.rates.USDNGN.rate,
          EUR: res.data.rates.USDEUR.rate,
          CNH: res.data.rates.USDCNH.rate,
          JPY: res.data.rates.USDJPY.rate,
          GBP: res.data.rates.USDGBP.rate,
          AUD: res.data.rates.USDAUD.rate,
          CAD: res.data.rates.USDCAD.rate,
          CHF: res.data.rates.USDCHF.rate,
          SEK: res.data.rates.USDSEK.rate,
          NZD: res.data.rates.USDNZD.rate
        });
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Infocard2 time={this.state.time} />
        <Forexcard
          NGN={this.state.NGN}
          EUR={this.state.EUR}
          CNH={this.state.CNH}
          JPY={this.state.JPY}
          GBP={this.state.GBP}
          AUD={this.state.AUD}
          CAD={this.state.CAD}
          CHF={this.state.CHF}
          SEK={this.state.SEK}
          NZD={this.state.NZD}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the major part. The other component part only contains a

tag that displays the data from the props

Comment: you need to share your code, show the attempt

Comment: Hard to say anything without seeing your code attempt, but you have to make a js/react function that appends a css class (either .up or .down, for example) to the currency rate element when the change happens. You could either time the script to remove the class and return the element's css to the initial state after xxx milliseconds, or you can probably achieve the same effect with only css.

Comment: Ok, i can show u the code. I am new to React so i am still trying to figure out how to do it.. I didnt code anything on it.